# Translating a sentence cointaining ても, と, とこ and 上 (colloquial japanese)

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, syntax

ＴＤＬって実は誘拐が多くて見つからないって本当ですか？なんでも迷子の呼び出しは規則**上**できないそうですね。迷子の子があつめられる**とこ**はあっ**ても**。そういう理由で誘拐しやすい**と**うわさになってるんですが。本当ですか。

This text is a post I found on a website. While translating it I had troubles with many things.

1. **規則上**: I don't know how to translate it since I've never seen this 
   use of 上.
2. **とこ**: is it equivalent to ところ?
3. **ても** at the end of a sentence: is that a colloquial rule or something? Does it mean "even if" anyways?
4. **と**: is there a verb like 思う omitted? Or is it a different use of the particle?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 上【じょう】 in 規則上【きそくじょう】 means something like "in relation to ～", "because of ～", "owing to ～", etc. Similar phrases are 立場上, 時間の関係上, 業務上, 都合上, and so on.
2. Yes, this とこ is simply ところ or (physical) *place*.
3. This ても is the [conjunctive ても](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-conditional-form-temo.html) meaning "even if". It normally precedes the main clause, as shown in the link, but here the ～ても clause is added as an afterthought, in a separate sentence. You can translate this as "～, though."
4. と is a quatative particle that is used with various verbs. Here it simply marks the content of 噂になる. People are rumoring that it's easy to kidnap in TDL.